# state is not defined in switch by javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use state in switch as props

if page is board, I want to get postData and PostLoading.
and then give it to pagePresenter. researchData and researchLoading are null.

below code show postData, postLoading, researchData, researchLoading is not defined.

```
export default ({
    match: {
      params: { code, page },
    },
  }) => {
      switch(page){
        case "board":
            const { data: postData, loading: postLoading } = useQuery(ALL_POST, {
              variables: { code },
              fetchPolicy: "network-only",
            });
            const onPostClick = (id, code) => {
              history.push(`/article/${code}/${id}`);
            };
            break;
          case "research":
            const { data: researchData, loading: researchLoading } = useQuery(
              ALL_RESEARCH,
              {
                variables: { code },
              }
            );
            break;
      
          default:
            return null;
      }
      return (
        <PagePresenter
        type={page}
        postLoading={postLoading ? postLoading : null}
        postData={postData ? postData : null}
        researchLoading={researchLoading ? researchLoading : null}
        researchData={researchData ? researchData : null}
      />
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that since you're declaring `const { data: postData, loading: postLoading }` inside the context of the `switch`, it'll be undefined outside of this context. Just like declaring a variable inside function. I suggest you take advantage of the `useState` hook. Simply initialise a blank state outside the `switch` and set it to `postData` after the `postData` is fetched.

So somewhere outside your `switch` do `const [postDataState, setPostData] = useState(undefined)` and then after you have your `postData`, do `setPostData(postData)`.

And finally, pass `postDataState` as props to your component. So instead of `postData={postData ? postData : null}` you'd say `postData={postDataState ? postDataState : null}`

Don't forget to `import {useState} from 'react'`